# How to set values using case statement in a select query?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I have a query like this

```
  left outer join ( select  tm.item_id as item_id,function_role =(CASE 
   mf.function_name
   when mf.function_name is not null 
   then mf.function_name
   else 'admin' 
   end)
   from team_members tm 
   join mem_function mf on mf.function_id=tm.function_id
   ) bnu on bnu.item_id = p.pro_id
```

When there's NO value in the function_name column of mem_function table,I want to set that value as 'admin'.
when i tried this it's throwing "From keyword not found where expected"
anyway to resolve this?

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL or .....?

Comment: @DineshDB mySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
left outer join
(select tm.item_id as item_id,
        coalesce(function_name, 'admin') as function_role
 from team_members tm join
      mem_function mf
      on mf.function_id = tm.function_id
) bnu
on bnu.item_id = p.pro_id
```

Although you can do this using `case`, `coalesce()` is really the better solution.

I think your problem involves the `function_role =`.  That assigns a variable, not a column name.

EDIT:

Your problem seems to be in the outer query.  So you want:

```
select . . ., coalesce(function_name, 'admin') as function_role
from . . .
left outer join
(select tm.item_id as item_id, function_name
 from team_members tm join
      mem_function mf
      on mf.function_id = tm.function_id
) bnu
on bnu.item_id = p.pro_id
```

You probably don't need the subqueries, but that is another matter.

Comment: still Can see null values instead of admin. doesn't seem to work

Comment: @KnowNothing . . . Of course you can.  You are doing a `left join`, so those are coming from unmatched records.  You have to fix that with `coalesce()` in the outer query.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time out to help me,It works now.